# Repeat row of data table N times and join to another table in R

Tags: r, join, datatable

I have two data tables:

```
> dt1

+---+---+
| V1| V2|
+---+---+
|  a|  a|
|  a|  b|
|  a|  c|
|  b|  c|
|  c|  d|
+---+---+

> dt2
+------------------+
|                id|
+------------------+
|  c(4, 98, 56, 32)|
+------------------+
```

`dt2` has the following structure:

```
> str(dt2)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ id:List of 1
  ..$ : int  4  98  56  32
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I am looking for the most efficient way (if possible, based on the `data.table` approach) to add column values from the `df2` as constant value to each row of the `df1`.
Expected result:

```
+---+---+------------------+
| V1| V2|                id|
+---+---+------------------+
|  a|  a|  c(4, 98, 56, 32)|
|  a|  b|  c(4, 98, 56, 32)|
|  a|  c|  c(4, 98, 56, 32)|
|  b|  c|  c(4, 98, 56, 32)|
|  c|  d|  c(4, 98, 56, 32)|
+---+---+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
dt1[, id:=dt2$id]
```

**Output:**

```
|V1 |V2 |id            |
|:--|:--|:-------------|
|a  |a  |c(4,98,56,32) |
|a  |b  |c(4,98,56,32) |
|a  |c  |c(4,98,56,32) |
|b  |c  |c(4,98,56,32) |
|c  |d  |c(4,98,56,32) |
```